# c++ error lnk2005 when a global function is included

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2012, lnk2005

I am working on a dll project, and it had been working well until I added a new .h, which includes a global function and a struct. Then the compiling (or link) failed.

Here is the error message:

```
1>RobotReality.obj : error LNK2005: "double __cdecl GetNumber(void)" (?GetNumber@@YANXZ) [[已经在 dllmain.obj 中定义  translate: this has been defined in dllmain.obj]]

1>stdafx.obj : error LNK2005: "double __cdecl GetNumber(void)" (?GetNumber@@YANXZ) [[已经在 dllmain.obj 中定义  translate: this has been defined in dllmain.obj]]
```

I have added `"#pragma once"` but the problem still exits.

How to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Check line number 17 of your .h file?!

Comment: move the global function to a .cpp file? keep the declaration （not the definition) of that function in the head.

Comment: Thanks @JohnSmith, the problem has been solved. And Thanks for editing. But I don't know how to choose a best answer? ....

Comment: Another alternative would have been to make the function inline. That said, there are no answers here to accept for you, because all those hints have been placed as mere comments.

Answer (score 0):

Declare them 'static' and let the compiler do the work.